# Should I use the same name for a member variable and a function parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, parameters, naming-conventions

I am wondering if it is a good practice to use the same name for both a *member variable* and a function *parameter* in C++.

I come from a Java background, where this was common. I am wondering if in C++ there are drawbacks doing the following (the code works):

```cpp
class Player
{
    public:
    void setState(PlayerState *state)
    {
        this->state = state;
    }

    private:
       PlayerState *state;
}
```

---

Thank you for the answers. As I understand while it works, a better practice would be to put some kind of marker to differentiate member variable from function parameters like:

```
 _ or m_
```

In some editors (like Qt Designer), member variables are shows in a different color. This is why it did not seem necessary to add any prefixes.

Comment: Purely a matter of choice and conventions followed by the coding guidelines of your organization.

Comment: I don't think there is any indication apart from not having to write the `this->`. I always use some kind of underscore before of after, but it is a matter of taste.

Comment: Some people, start the attrib names with m, for example here will be mState, is better to do that way if the code is modified by someone else, ever the more readeable is your code, better

Comment: Careful with `set`/`get` members, or you'll end up with [quasi-classes](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf) [PDF].

Comment: I use a capitalized 'F' for 'Field', but that's just historical. If you use an initializer list, it's clearer what is being assigned to what, (unless it's C#, then you can't).

Comment: Prefixes don't generalize well to structs unfortunately

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is correct, and allowed by the Standard. But a better approach is to use some naming-convention for member variables. For example, you could use `m_` prefix for all member variables, then anyone could infer what `m_state` is. It increases the readability of the code, and avoids common mistakes.

Also, if `m_state` is the member, then you don't have to write `this->m_state  = state` in the member function, you could just write `m_state = state`. In your current code, `this->` part becomes necessary, without which `state = state` will become self-assignment.

Comment: What would happen if "this" is excluded (state=state)? That means function parameter probably takes more priority and hence class variable is not set I guess!

Comment: @Rajesh apart from in a c'tors initializer list: yes.

Answer (score 10):

Normally people just put an underscore after the variable or use shorter less descriptive var names for the function parameter.

I personally do not like the same name thing because when reading it, it is easy to make mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

I find it a good choice to give *member variables* the same name as constructor initialization *parameters*.

Here are my reasons:

- reduces the number of identifiers, hence reduces the complexity
- you don't need to invent so many identifiers
- same things should have same name if possible, that is logically speaking, I know
  `parameter != member`
- contexts and indices can allow to give the same name to the same thing
- you more easily find references (identifiers) to the logical thing by searching,
  if all references have the same name

Answer (score 3):

There is not really any difference between the C++ and Java, the only drawback is that you have to type `this->state = state` instead of `state = arg`.

But your code is perfectly acceptable, it's more of styling than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to follow some coding style convention. Personally I use the:

```
class Player
{
    public:
    void setState(PlayerState *state)
    {
        _state = state;
    }

    private:
       PlayerState* _state;
}
```

Comment: I personally I do like the the leading underscores as they are generally for the standard library and compiler functions. I do like the trailing underscores.

Comment: I don't like any underscores!  With name-mangling,  __attrib etc. I've seen enough underscores in C++ as it is!

Comment: All of these are depending on which coding styles your company is following. The leading underscore is quite common in many c# and java coding style guides :).

Comment: Also the lead underscore is allowed if it is not followed by the Capital letter. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)

Comment: @AlexTheo Officially.  In practice, you increase the risk of conflict with a leading underscore (and your never free from some compiler defining a symbol with no underscore---I've had problems with simply `linux`).  More generally, leading and trailing underscores should be avoided because they're hard to see, and make reading the code more difficult.  There's only one character difference between `myState` and `_state`, and the former is so much more readable.

Comment: @JamesKanze probably you are right :). I will check if I need to change my coding guidlines. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a style issue than anything else.  Most of the time,
there's no issue: `state` is a very poor name for a variable or a value,
as variables and values should be qualified nouns, e.g.:

```
void setState( PlayerState* newState )
{
    currentState = newState;
}
```

In theory, anyway.  In practice, I've found it useful to use prefixes,
along the lines of:

```
class Player
{
    PlayerState* myState;
public:
    void setState( PlayerState* newState )
    {
        myState = newState;
    }
};
```

When reading the code, if the name starts with `my`, it's clearly a
member variable (and if it starts with `our`, it's a static member
variable).

Note too that in the constructor, you can do things like:

```
Player::Player( PlayerState* state )
    : state( state )
{
}
```

I'm not sure what this does for readability, however:

```
Player::Player( PlayerState* initialState )
    : myState( initialState )
{
}
```

looks a lot clearer (but for simple data holders, the distinction might
not be so significant).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that some compilers ([vs 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/11/12/improvements-to-warnings-in-the-c-compiler/)) may generate a warning if a variable shadows another. Off course, one can disable these kind of warnings. But I think it is good practice to have these checks enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the member initializer list you can get away without using `this->`:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:17,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:17,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:17,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:17,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Astruct+mystruct%0A%7B%0A++++mystruct(int+a,+bool+b)%0A++++++++:+++a%7Ba%7D%0A++++++++,+++b%7Bb%7D%0A++++%7B%7D%0A++++int+a%3B%0A++++bool+b%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++mystruct+s%7B1,true%7D%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Os+-pthread%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>

struct mystruct
{
    mystruct(int a, bool b)
        :   a{a}
        ,   b{b}
    {}
    int a;
    bool b;
};


int main()
{
    mystruct s{1,true};
}
```

I use this for a simple struct which doesn't need a public private differentiation. I think it's good form bc for this case you can "imitate" aggregate initialization

```
mystruct s = { 1, true }
```

and have the constructor just appear to "route through" the entries to the according data members.

Comment: Just to note that [member initializer lists](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/constructor-member-initializer-lists/) are C++11. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Explanation

Answer (score 0):

It's fine, in-fact it might even be good form, so long as it's only ever in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
class Player
{
    public:
    void setState(PlayerState *state)
    {
        this->m_state = state;
    }

    private:
       PlayerState *m_state;
}
```

You'll thank me some time later on. Haha.. (:

The "m_" ("Member") prefix distinguish members from functions and other stuff. Very useful with stuff like intellisense (or any other IDE auto-suggestion).

Also, mark `m_state` as `const` if you do not intend to change it later. Just in case.

Comment: Making `m_state` `const` means that you can't support assignment.

Comment: @JamesKanze it actually depends where you put the `const` keyword - before the type, after it, or after the asterik etc' :)

Comment: Given that `m_state` has a pointer type, the only place you can put the `const` to make it `const` is after the `*`.  Otherwise, you're not making `m_state` `const`, you're making what it points to `const`.  (And if I were going to comment on something beyond the actual question, I'd ask why it was a pointer to begin with.  `PlayerState` sounds like a value to me.)

Comment: @Poni actually, putting `const` before or after the type causes the same functionality (re-assignable pointer to constant PlayerState); after the asterisk is different (constant pointer to mutable PlayerState).  Neither of these sound like a good idea for this example.  [Understanding `const`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html) is prerequisite to using it.