# class member is another class' object

Tags: c++, class, opencv, initializer

I am a new C++ user...

I have a question regarding how to declare a member of a class "classA" that is an object of another class "classB", knowing that "classB" has a constructor that takes a string parameter (in addition to the default contructor). I did some research online about this issue however it did not help much to help me fix the issue I'm dealing with.

To be more specific, I want to create a class that has as member a VideoCapture object (VideoCapture is an openCV class that provide a video stream).

My class has this prototype :

```
class  myClass {
private:

string videoFileName ;

public:

myClass() ;

~myClass() ;

myClass (string videoFileName) ;
// this constructor will be used to initialize myCapture and does other
// things

VideoCapture myCapture (string videoFileName /* :  I am not sur what to put here */ )  ;

};
```

the constructor is :

```
myClass::myClass (string videoFileName){

VideoCapture myCapture(videoFileName) ;
// here I am trying to initialize myClass' member myCapture BUT
// the combination of this line and the line that declares this
// member in the class' prototype is redundant and causes errors...

// the constructor does other things here... that are ok...

}
```

I did my best to expose my issue in the simplest way, but I'm not sure I managed to...

Thank you for your help and answers.

L.

Comment: Your private member variable is has the same name as your constructor argument.  That's going to screw you over.

Comment: @m24p not if coded properly it won't. The OP needs an initializer list; the variable names are irrelevant here.

Comment: If coded properly, it won't have a member variable with the same name as a constructor argument.

There is no good reason in this case to give them the exact same name.  And it will screw you over in terms of code maintainability if nothing else.

Comment: @m24p it might screw  *you* over; Neither I nor most of contributors to this board have a problem with it. There is no problem with using the same name save for you not wanting to use the same name. To each their own.

Comment: @WhozCraig  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250016/should-i-use-the-same-name-for-a-member-variable-and-a-function-parameter-in-c

I'm not going to -1 you, but saying "most of [stack overflow contributors have] no problem with it" appears incorrect.  Do you have a citation to back that?

Comment: @m24p didn't know I needed one. And three up-votes doesn't constitute a mandate regardless. I've posted an answer now, so feel free to -1 it regardless of the correctness. It wouldn't be the first time, and certainly won't be the last. Would be too bad, as it appears to be the only one that bothers to mention the importance of member initialization  in relation to declaration within the class.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is initializer list:

```
myClass::myClass (string videoFileName) : myCapture(videoFileName) {
}
```

This will construct `myCapture` using its constructor that takes a `string` argument.

Comment: Not that it is necessarily clear, but `videoFileName(videoFileName)` should probably also be in that list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a VideoCapture to be a member of the class, you don't want this in your class definition:

```
VideoCapture myCapture (string videoFileName /* :  I am not sur what to put here */ )  ;
```

Instead you want this:

```
VideoCapture myCapture;
```

Then, your constructor can do this:

```
myClass::myClass (string PLEASE_GIVE_ME_A_BETTER_NAME)
: myCapture(PLEASE_GIVE_ME_A_BETTER_NAME),
videoFileName(PLEASE_GIVE_ME_A_BETTER_NAME)
{
}
```